# Когда применяют АОП spring boot?

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

Когда нужно что-то перехватить можем применить аспекты, например для логирования или аудита. У меня кейс для перехвата ошибок, есть асинхронный вызов компонента, (производительность не нужна), в котором есть пару бизнес сценариев, где может произойти exception, я поставил аспект на этот метод, и если ошибка, обрабатываю,нужно пробросить ошибку в камунду в external task, все работает правильно,но мне сказали что аспекты тут неуместны, неподходящий инструмент. В итоге переделал на try catch с публикацией события, и вот вопрос когда использовать аспекты? Разве в этом кейсе плохо?